# Is there any property ordering convention in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, conventions, coding-style

For any class in Kotlin I generally have bunch of different properties. I wanted to know if there is any conversion in ordering of those properties according to their type. Basic types that I use are

- `var fields`
- `private var fields`
- `lateinit var fields`
- `private lateinit var fields`
- everything above with `val fields`
- `lazy fields`
- `private lazy fields`
- etc.

Well common classification would be having same kind of properties to be declared in a same group. Then what I do is try to declare public fields first then private ones. I was wondering how how about, what about what comes first for say `lazy` and `lateinit`. Or what will come after `var`? `private var` or `lateinit var` or `lazy val`?

Well I know that one can write however they please, but I was wondering if there is any convention, that lists properties according to their certain unspecified level?

Answer (score 7):

From [the Kotlin docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html):

> Do not sort the method declarations alphabetically or by visibility,
> and do not separate regular methods from extension methods. Instead,
> put related stuff together, so that someone reading the class from top
> to bottom would be able to follow the logic of what's happening.
> Choose an order (either higher-level stuff first, or vice versa) and
> stick to it.

I think this rule can be also applied to the properties.

Answer (score 0):

I followed practice like Java / C# programming language:

```
First public, then protected, then package level (no access modifier), and then private.
```

https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-fileorganization.html

```
Public.
Internal.
Protected internal.
Protected.
Private.
```

https://google.github.io/styleguide/csharp-style.html

**put related stuff together** sometimes is harder for the practice, especially for field declaration